# What is the main difference between " const char* " and " const char " apart from one being a pointer

Tags: c++

This is the code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    const char* message{"Hello world."};
    std::cout << "message : " << message << std::endl;

    //*message = 'B'; //compiler error
    std::cout << "*message : " << *message << std::endl;

    //Allow users to modify the string
    const char message1[]{"Hello world"};
    message1[0] = 'B';

    return 0;
}
```

I don't really see any difference between them and in which situation one or the other can be apply.

Lasty, How do we print out the address of pointer initialized with string?

Comment: The code snippet actually demonstrates the differences. What is confusing about it?

Comment: `message1[0] = 'B';` won't compile, you can't change `message1`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I feel like maybe they (or whoever who made the snippet) made a mistake copying a guide to the differences when the array is non-`const`, but yeah, the snippet as written is wrong.

Comment: The duplicate I linked is the C duplicate, but aside from the whole "C string literals are technically not `const`, but modifying them is undefined so they may as well be `const`", the info is the same. Having trouble finding the C++-specific duplicate (which I'm sure exists).

Comment: To print the address, use something like ``std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(message)``.  (I think that part of the question is not addressed in the linked answer.)